# Is using the applet class in a Java game a wise thing to do?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making an 2D multiplayer game in Java project, by using Java sockets and simple  `java.applet.*`

Our teacher told us to use J2EE concepts in the project. Do I have to use JSP? Is it better or more employable in game development?

Am I doing the correct thing?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your teacher?

Comment: she said that we can do scripting with javascript, said something about servlets and was vague...

Answer (score 1):

Java applets are used for embedding Java applications in web pages. You should create an applet if, and only if, you are intending to do that — to provide your users a GUI written in Java which requires them to have a JRE installed on their computer.

From your other descriptions, it sounds like you are supposed to be making a web app — the game logic resides on your web server, and the interface is implemented in HTML and JavaScript. There are no applets involved here. This generally results in a more widely compatible and faster-loading interface. However, the HTTP request/response model means that it is more complex to build simple interactive interfaces robustly.

Personally, I would recommend reading up on the architecture of web applications before attempting to write one which is a game.