# Can J2EE be used to implement games ? Is there any connection between J2EE and games?

Tags: java

Making an game using applets, but have to implement project using J2EE. Is there any sense in making a game with using J2EE for implementation ?

Our teacher said that we can make games for the java project, now she has put in the requirement that we have to use J2EE, and expects us to make the game. Where does J2EE comes in the picture ?

Comment: I guess you haven't asked your teacher yet? Possible duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26419/is-using-the-applet-class-in-a-java-game-a-wise-thing-to-do

Answer (score 2):

J2EE is the superset for Java SE and Java ME, meaning that you have as many libraries available as you would for those two.

Now, it does not make much sense choosing EE, because most of the additions are oriented to big servers and databases.

Answer (score 0):

As Ef Es said J2EE is the superset for J2SE. Your teacher may have wanted you to use either  a database or a server for your game to communicate with.